# Landlord/Property managers broke contract (I think) but I never did anything about it due to hassle involved, what are my options now?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, contracts

So, about a year ago some people came in and changed the **Electric** and **Gas** meters to Pay as you go meters because the landlord hadn't paid the bills. Since my contract was an all-inclusive contract that means (I think) they (the Landlord/Property managers) broke the contract (which by definition, can't be all-inclusive if I have to pay for something that's supposed to be included, separately), they (the Landlord/Property managers) are also still getting people to sign all-inclusive contracts!

Now I didn't do anything about this at the time because of the hassle involved in dealing with this & also trying to find a new place and anything else.

My initial year contract is over and I'm now on just a rolling contract, which means they may try to increase the price.

So I'm wondering, what are my options should say the Landlord/Property managers put the rent up?

But also what are my options in general?

Comment: Without a contract, I suspect the landlord can raise the rent, and you are free to either accept the increase or move, just as you are free to move at any time without having to pay a penalty for leaving early.

Comment: I suggest taking out the part about is it a single or double. It’s irrelevant. Your question seems to be the first paragraph, and is a good one. What they can do with the rent during the month to month phase is a separate Q.

Comment: Try harder to find a new place.  One which doesn't have an abusive landlord.

Comment: Did you try to get in touch with Citizens Advice ? They deal with such issues and might be able to advise you legally.

Comment: @chepner: he does have a contract. Once the fixed term is over, the contract continues on the same terms, but month-to-month (this is tagged UK, so I'm assuming it's an assured shorthold tenancy).

Comment: About the rent: I believe, on a rolling contract in the UK, the Landlord/Agency has the right to "adjust" (=increase) the rent once a year. Your option is, I believe, to accept the new rent offer or leave if they try to up it. But, out of curiosity: did you end up paying for the electric and gas over this one year period yourself, on top of your rent? In which case it seems like the Landlord/Agency broke the contract, but especially a year later, I don't think I would know how to approach it without legal help (and _I personally_ would most likely just let it go and move on)

Comment: @penelope, no I didn't, I took the amount from the rent that I paid for the utility.